# Netflix not working in Windows Vista Media Center two icons, and won't play

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-center, htpc, netflix

Two part question.

1. Why does Windows Media Center display two Netflix plugins on the main home screen?
2. Why does Netflix have a popup saying "there was a problem retrieving data, please check your internet connection" and won't load any data, but playback streams just fine via web browser?

I've been using Netflix plugin for Windows Media Center for several months without issues. The second icon on the home screen of WMC showed up sometime last week, and it stopped playback entirely the other day.

Vista x86, Home Premium. I have uninstalled the plugin, deleted registry entries, reinstalled silverlight, and still have the same issue.

Comment: Vista x64 or x86?

Comment: Having this same exact problem.  Other people report this may have happened after a windows update.  I've found no solution yet.

Comment: I uninstalled all the updates that were applied when this started happening (~12/8), and it's still broken.

Comment: It resolved itself through no action of mine on 12/16.  Go figure.

Comment: @rfusca Thanks, I'll give it a peek tonight when I get off work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked my Netflix VMC plugin (the first icon to the left of Recorded TV) and it worked just fine. Must have been a problem on Netflix's end that they resolved in the last day or two. I didn't have to restart or reinstall anything either, it just worked.